# Dialog box scrollview won't wrap content correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout in a dialog box, and need it to be scrollable so that phones with smaller screens can view the whole thing. However, when I contain the rest of my layout in a scrollview it makes it way too long with a lot of space at the bottom.

I have set the scrollview height to wrap_content, but this doesn't change anything, can anybody see any problems with my xml that would make it do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/allowanceroot"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogsetminutes"
    android:text="@string/setminutesallowance"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
></TextView>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/minutesinput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
></EditText>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogsetmessages"
    android:text="@string/setmessagesallowance"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
></TextView>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messagesinput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
></EditText>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogsetdata"
    android:text="@string/setdataallowance"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
></TextView>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/datainput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Its working Fine .. No issues on my system :)

Comment: Wraps the stuff inside the scrollview correctly? I've tried it in the emulator as well and there's a lot of empty space at the bottom

Comment: I have just copy pasted your code,made minor changes like change TExtView , and in my activity class i have created a AlterDialog Builder and its works fine ....

Comment: I'll do the same to see if I can work it out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code (may be useful for u )

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayoutName,null);
    builder.setView(layout);
    builder.show();
```